# How to know that if firebase spark plan limitations are for per project or for total project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, limit, firebase-storage

I have a firebase project. I'm intending to add another project for my new app. I know the cloud firestore and storage limitations but I'm not sure if this limitations ar set for per project individually or been set for my firebase account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark plan limitations are per project. You can check all limitations and pricing on the official documentation regarding [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) where it is also mentioned. Please also note, that multiple databases are also allowed per project.

Comment: Thank you. And What's about firebase storage? Is it also set for per project?

Comment: Multiple buckets per project. See the link about pricing. You're welcome, cheers!

Comment: Thank you dude, you saved my life!